# JS defer and jQuery ready event

Tags: jquery

I have added `defer` atribute to my jquery script to increase web page performance but now I get error `$ is not defined`. I need to execute JS code when page loads so I use jQuery.ready event but it do not work when defer is used.

```
<head>    
    <script defer="defer" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
          //MyLoadCode
        });
    </script>

</head>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The defer attribute, when present, specifies that the script is executed when the page has finished parsing. But you are using the jquery variable `$` before the page has finished parsing and at that time the jquery script is not loaded and has not initialized `$`.

Instead of using the defer attribute, move the script-tags from the header to the bottom of the page, just before the `</body>` tag.

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>

        ... 

        <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>


        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
              //MyLoadCode
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the script to load till late, then move the jquery script to the bottom of the html page. Then it will be loaded last.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure jQuery is loaded before using `$`, so you should not defer loading jQuery.

If you want to defer load jQuery, you need to add your javascript which uses jQuery into the the script onload success event handler.

Answer (score 0):

You cant use  `$(document).ready(function () {` and wait unit the the DOM has loaded because that very statement is a jQuery symbol, which is defered and not yet available. So, the `$` variable can only be used when jQuery is loaded immidiately.

Answer (score 0):

Generally it's cleaner to use an explicit callback over polling, but the advantages of loading scripts with `defer` can make a simple call to `setTimeout()` worth it.

```html
<head>
   <script defer src=https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.6/dist/jquery.min.js></script>
   <script>
      const myApp = () => {
         console.log('Page ready:', $('h1').text());
         console.log('My app is running.');
         };
   </script>
   <script>
      const onReady = () =>
         typeof $ === 'function' ? $(myApp) : setTimeout(onReady, 100);
      onReady();
   </script>
</head>
```

The `typeof` command checks if **jQuery** is loaded.  If not, wait 100 milliseconds and check again.  (Note that with `setTimeout()` each call to `onReady()` is independent so there is no *recursive call stack* to overflow.)

This polling strategy is not specific to **jQuery.**

You can use this strategy to wait for any library:

```html
<script>
   const onReady = () =>
      typeof xLib !== 'undefined' ? myApp() : setTimeout(onReady, 100);
   window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', onReady);
</script>
```

**External JS File**
Alternatively, you can take advantage of the fact that `defer` scripts are guaranteed to be executed in order, but this *requires* putting your code in a separate file.

Load required libraries before your code:

```html
<head>
   <script defer src=https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.6/dist/jquery.min.js></script>
   <script defer src=my-app.js></script>
</head>
```